# Plural Forms error in Query Monitor

Tags: plugins, errors

Greatings,

My theme support sad that it's coming from Wordpress this error. Maybe somebody encountered same error?

Adding a photo.

[image]

Comment: Well they're wrong. Based on your screenshot the error is clearly caused by the theme's `WR_Nitro_Header_Builder::bulk_updated_messages()` function. Did you show them this screenshot?

Comment: Yup. Sad it's coming from WP

Comment: ""Hi,

As I explained above, it comes from WordPress system itself, you can see directly in the error and it affects the theme file which works base on those files.

Please kindly recheck and fix these WordPress errors first, the theme file error will be gone following it.

Thank you""

Theme answer

Comment: Then they clearly don’t even know how to debug their own software. I’d just find another theme. These guys don’t know what they’re doing.